Typeguard for array
I have difficulties with typescript. One of my variable can have a string or array of string value. I would like to use a typeguard to use join function only on arrays. It looks like it ignores my condition.
Does anyone have an idea how to make a proper type narrowing here?
const x = (value: string | string[]) => {
    return Array.isArray(value) ? value.join(',') : value
}

Typescript message:

Property 'join' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'. Property 'join' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)


There are no type errors in this code in Typescript 5.6

Please [edit] your code to be a [mre]. Right now the problem you're showing can't be reproduced, so the question risks being closed as lacking debugging details.

Maybe your editor has cached something? Have you tried reloading it?

Even though you’re using Array.isArray(value) to check if value is an array, TypeScript might still be confused about the type because the type of value is string | string[].
To fix this, you can use TypeScript’s type assertion to explicitly tell the compiler that value is an array inside the if block. Here’s how you can adjust your function:
const x = (value: string | string[]): string => {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        // TypeScript now knows `value` is `string[]`
        return value.join(',');
    } else {
        // `value` is `string` here
        return value;
    }
}

By adding the if block, TypeScript can infer the type correctly.

LLM hallucination?!
